# conditional variable in object

Tags: javascript, object, shorthand, conditional-statements

Just tried to do something like this and it wont work, wondering if there is anyway?

```
var obj = {
    intiger:5,
    conditional:(something) ? "something" : "nothing",
    string:"nothing important"
};
```

This is breaking because of the presence of the `:` within the `conditional`. Anyway to do this without it breaking and keeping this format of `obj`.

I know that I can do.

```
obj.conditional = (something) ? "something" : "nothing";
```

Comment: My code was different then the example above and was missing a parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use another set of parenthesis?

```
...
conditional:((something)?"something":"nothing"),
...
```

Just have to let the parser know which `:` to pay attention to and for which purpose.

```
var foo = {
    bar: (true ? "true" : "false")
};
console.log(foo.bar); // true
```

You can also use a `function(){}` if the decision needs to be made at the time of reference. e.g.

```
var foo = {
    bar:function(){
        return this.baz == 'Brad' ? 'Me' : 'Not Me';
    },
    baz: 'Brad'
};
console.log(foo.bar()); // 'Me'
foo.baz = 'Thomas'; console.log(foo.bar()); // 'Not Me'
```